# Storing local path in NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c

Question regarding getting URL of a file in document folder.

I'm trying to take local URL to next viewcontroller to play the song.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
MSHLocalPlayerVC *playerVC = [segue destinationViewController];
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strURL = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: [self.filePathArray objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]];

playerVC.urlLocalSong = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
...
}
```

result:

strURL:
 `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/64000095-51F9-47D1-B152-6D1F8369A01F/Documents/mySong.mp3`

playerVC.urlLocalSong: `nil`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use `playerVC.urlLocalSong = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strURL];`